# Cannot deploy traefik with consul

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, consul, traefik

I'm trying to deploy a traefik stack on docker with consul as a key / value store. My cluster is made of three nodes (three masters) :

```
ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
rqg08lc4ixgjuo1azi57654z1 *   tools-master-1      Ready               Active              Leader              18.03.1-ce
vi42z7f8dx6bgrhzbda8v7z15     tools-master-2      Ready               Active              Reachable           18.03.1-ce
khz5x5g28i64owyo8tykedern     tools-master-3      Ready               Active              Reachable           18.03.1-ce
```

Every node is on a different sever. To limit as much as I can any potential error on my side, I tried to use Traefik's official documentation and strictly stick to it; I've used this link : https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/cluster-docker-consul/

The swarm cluster itself is working (i can deploy other services on it and everything seems to be ok). However, I cannot get traefik to work.

I've pinned it down to a point where I've did the following :
- start with an empty, newly created VM
- Install docker and basic stuff like that
- Copy the exact same docker-compose as the one at the end of the traefik's official documentation (with three exception, see below)
- Launch `docker stack deploy testing -c /path/to/my/docker-compose.yml`

The three only differences are:
- I obviously changed email and domain to put my own ones
- I removed the line "driver" from the volume for consul since my docker instance does not seems to recognize when i ask for overlay2... however according to https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/#docker-ee-and-cs-engine it's supposed to be the default anyway.

Problem is : traefik doesn't seems to be able to communicate with consul. Here is traefik's output :

```
testing_traefik.0.yy6vfo4qo3kl@tools-master-1    | time="2018-06-06T20:53:05Z" level=error msg="Load config error: Get http://consul:8500/v1/kv/traefik?consistent=&recurse=&wait=30000ms: dial tcp: lookup consul on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host, retrying in 20.35838976s"
```

From what I guess, consul cannot be found (or the dns itself cannot be found by traefik). However, the services are up :

```
ID                  NAME                   MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE               PORTS
e78d24w45wzd        testing_consul         replicated          1/1                 consul:latest
o1dzrdqeoiy0        testing_traefik        global              3/3                 traefik:1.5
om8qac3upy22        testing_traefik_init   replicated          0/1                 traefik:1.5
```

I thought it might come from the host-only networking. So i've decided to try by stripping traefik of every port (making it useless, but right now I just want it to talk with consul). I also removed the "webgateway" network (again, testing). No more luck... And since this is the official documentation's example, I don't really have a clue about where to look for something more.

So, here come the question... Do anyone have any idea of what could cause this error ? Or any other way to make traefik work on a swarm cluster with let's encrypt ?

Thank you !

PS : docker install + server provisionning are done using terraform + ansible. I doubt those two things could be the origin of the problem, but it it may help in any way to investigate, I can share the .tf / .yml files.

**Edit**: I also found out the the dns resolution problem seemed to appear when a service wanted to talk / identify another one if the two aren't on the same swarm node.

I've added a debian service to my docker-compose, then went inside the container. From there:
- When I try to ping "traefik" (traefik being a global service in the docker-compose, it is present on every node), I can
- When I try to ping "shell" (the container I added), which is not it's hostname and as such go through DNS discovery, I can
- When I try to ping "consul" (which is on another node), I can't, the dns resolution fail.

So I suspect a problem on my configuration of docker ? If that may help, here is the output of a docker info in one of the swarm agent (they are all installed using the same ansible task so their info should be the same) :

```
Containers: 3
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 2
Server Version: 18.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: rqg08lc4ixgjuo1azi57654z1
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: nydyw0ufzgy6739u15xvt1pts
 Managers: 3
 Nodes: 3
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 10
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
 Autolock Managers: false
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: 10.15.15.39
 Manager Addresses:
  10.14.109.15:2377
  10.15.1.25:2377
  10.15.15.39:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.127-mainline-rev1
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 995.2MiB
Name: tools-master-1
ID: YFOZ:HA4F:UG52:EAGR:6G5O:554H:XXFO:YCGW:Q5CB:YQDF:OB7W:TYMB
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: Maybe you could share your docker-compose.yml please? I'm having other problem with a cluster, it can't find `traefik/` in consul at all. So everything that tries to access it from `traefik` container - fails.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to this post : https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1429 i've found out the issue.

The problem came from two main sources :

First, the communication between nodes must be allowed on ports 7946 tcp/udp and 4789 udp (and 2377 for masters but that was already done on my case)

Second, the default subnet's IP seems to interfere with docker's dns. It need to be changed as such :

```
networks:
  traefik:
    driver: overlay
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.0.0/24
```

(Whatever the subnet as long as it does not have the ip 172.0.0.11 which is docker's dns IP)